# <div>'s automatically adding a gap/padding/margin when content is added

Tags: css, html, margin, padding

I made a simple site using stack-able `div`s inside of a wrapper `div`. The problem is that every time I add content to the , it suddenly adds a space of some type, and I cannot get rid of it. The content in the `div`s will be dynamic so the `height` won't be always the same.

Why does this happen? Is it a problem the `div` or the content itself?

Image below the div's without content

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wbPfwfW.png]

Image below the div's with content

[image: http://i.imgur.com/R6ycvYP.png]

My CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Basic */
body {
    background-color: #666;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #999;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #9C0;
}
#menubar {
    width: 900px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #906;
}
#content {
    width: 900px;
    height: 350px;  
    position: relative;
    background-color: #036;
}
#footer {
    width: 900px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F90;
}

/* Nav */
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff; 
}
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="menubar">
  <ul id="nav" >
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you normalizing the CSS?

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 i dont know what that is, i googled the term and this came up http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/ is that what you were saying?

Comment: Basically doing something like `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` in order to remove browser specific defaults.

Comment: Check that your content files aren't encoded in UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: Check this page : [cssreset](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the CSS you provided, it seems that you are forgetting to normalize it. Add at the very least this to the top of your CSS file:

```
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
```

This will remove any browser specific margins or padding from elements, which may be causing the whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a css script called Normalize.css which makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.
You can download it from: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1):

for me I had the same issue with CSS NORMALIZER

and I just add this css code to the main container:

```
border: 1px solid transparent;
```

seems to be working on all major browsers along with IEs except IE6 gives you a black border b'cause as you may know IE6 does not support TRANSPARENCY

hope this helps :-)

Comment: after I worked on my page and added more contents to it, I realized that ( jimjimmy1995 ) is method is what you need to do... b'cause other wise you're gonna end up having more of 1pxs on every corner of your site because of BORDER 1PX SOLID...

anyway I hope I explain it well.. thankx and thankx to ( jimjimmy1995 )